# Traversing through Matrix in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a simple tictactoe game to learn the syntax and keep getting an error `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` when running the following:

```
board = [ 
            ['|', '|', '|' ],
            ['|', '|', '|'],
            ['|', '|', '|'] 
        ] 

def tictactoe ():

    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in board]))

    print(len(board))

    for i in range(0,len(board)):
        for j in range(0,len(i)):
            print(i,j)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the second line of your for loop:

```
for j in range(0, len(i))
```

This won't work since you're trying to get the length of i which is an integer value here. Instead, you can just go through the range of i as:

```
for j in range(0, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int has no len()` implies you are calling `len` on an `int`. Scanning your code shows `len(i)` is the only place `len` is called. And indeed, if you use `for i in range(...)` then `i` will be an `int`.

Perhaps you meant to use

```
for i in range(0,len(board)):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(i,j)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,len(board)):
    for j in range(0,len(i)):
        print(i,j)
```

You declared *i* as an **int** in the first line here. just use

```
for j in range(0, i)
```